# jQuery Datepicker Date Formatting Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I am new to jQuery so bear with me here. I have set my code set up so that when the user clicks on a certain date on the jQuery calendar, it displays the date that they have selected. I just want it to show the date in the format of "mm-dd-yyyy" but everything I have tried does not affect the date output.

This is the bare jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function init (){

    $("#datepicker").datepicker({

        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',

        onSelect: function() {

            var userdate = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");

            document.getElementById("userdate").innerHTML = userdate;

        }

    });

});
```

Here is a plunker of my bare code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/T8ARyYg2qZna9QvPGg8m?p=preview

Thank you!

Comment: you need to use `onSelect: function(dateText)` .check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kdevL1om/2/

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but if you want the format `mm-dd-yy`, why not just set it -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ma1jheno/1/**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code:

```
var userdate = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
```

By:

```
var userdate = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
```

Answer (score 1):

just change your `onSelect` function like this

```
onSelect: function(dateText) {

    var userdate = dateText;

    document.getElementById("userdate").innerHTML = userdate;

}
```

your code should look like this

```
$(document).ready(function init() {

    $("#datepicker").datepicker({

        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',

        onSelect: function(dateText) {

            var userdate = dateText;

            document.getElementById("userdate").innerHTML = userdate;
        }

    });

});
```

here's a working **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kdevL1om/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formatDate function:

```
var userdate = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate"))
```